# In order to get Billing Agreement Id do we need to get Merchant enabled for reference transactions?

Tags: paypal

I am trying to get BillingAgreemntId using "SetExpressCheckout" and "CreateBillingAgreement"
but getting response as

```
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Merchant not enabled for reference transactions&
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Merchant not enabled for reference transactions&
```

How to get the account enabled for reference transactions to get BillingAgreementId?

I am sorry if this invalid to ask it here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call PayPal to request the billing agreement to be enabled on your account.

Comment: I requested paypal about it. Thanks.